# Use twice postive lookahead not work on .Net 1.1

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I use RegularExpressionValidator control to verify TextBox control named TextBox1, the web form in VS2003 Web application, like below:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Fromat error."
 ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,10}$" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

When I input string "qwer1asd", it does not match. But the same regular expression:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,10}$
```

...matches in JavaScript.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?=.{8,10}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$
```

There's a bug in older versions of Internet Explorer (described [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug)) that caused a regex like this to fail in the client even though it worked on the server.  (That sounds like the opposite of what you're describing, but I don't see any other reason why your regex would fail.)  Moving the length check to the first lookahead is the proven workaround for the bug.

Comment: Thank your answer. Yes, I tried to browse using IE6/7/8/9, IE6/7 was fail, but IE8/9 was correct. And use your answer, IE6/7/8/9 was correct. Thanks.